# how to access overridden, non static method of abstract class in subclass

Tags: java, overriding

In my program there are only two classes one is Parent ,which is an abstract class and having a non static concrete method, void show(), now there is another class, Child which extends the abstract class, Parent and override the show() method. So now is there any way to access the method of abstract class from main method of Child class with out calling another non static method of Child class.

Comment: You can access inside the `Child.show()` method by calling `super.show()`

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: Please post answers as answers, rather than comments.

Comment: but for this I will have to either create constructor and then call to super, or to create a non static method in Child class then call to super.show and now in main method create the object of Child class then call to the non static method,is it possible to do this from main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
super.show();
```

although that'll only work from within a (non-static) member function of the subclass.

There's no direct way to call an overridden method from another class.  Your only option would be to have the subclass expose a new method that does nothing but call the parent's overridden method.

However if you do need to do that it suggests that your class hierarchy is incorrectly designed...

Comment: could you please tell how to do this from main method as main does not allow to call super

Comment: @user571616 you can't (directly).

Answer (score 3):

Since `Child.show()` is static, you must do this:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    static void show() {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.myShow();
    }

    void show() {
         super.show();
    }
}
```

**Answer to the edited post**: you cannot call a non-static method without an instance. Every other detail of this situation is irrelevant if you can't/don't want to create an instance of either `Parent` or `Child`, as it is just no possible. The question now becomes: Why would you want to do that? What are trying to achieve?

Comment: (from within a call to any non-static `Child` method)

Comment: Obviously: static from static and instance, instance from instance only.

Comment: If someone doesn't know about `super`, it's not obvious at all. `super` only exists in non-static methods. In static methods, sadly, you have to actually resort to the base class name or various mechanations.

Comment: True, but it's a more general concept that you can't call a non-static method (base class' or otherwhise) from a static context.

Comment: but for this I will have to either create constructor and then call to super, or to create a non static method in Child class then call to super.show and now in main method create the object of Child class then call to the non static method,is it possible to do this from main method

Comment: If `Child.show()` and `Parent.show()` are both non-static, you only have to call `super.show()` inside any non-static Child method. If `Child.show()` is static (that would be a terrible, terrible design) then you need some instance of `Parent` to call `show()` on.

Comment: yes that is the actual question, as Parent is abstract, so we can't create instance of this class, and from main method we can't call super   as super can't call from static context. that's why I was asking is there any direct way from main method to call Parent class show() method

Comment: "some instance of `Parent`" mean that you can use an instance of `Child`, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: If it isn't, the OP is __really__ confused (he probably is anyway). I'm flagging this question as it is going nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

To access parent methods you prefix the call with "super". So, in your case use:

```
super.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

A child class can always use the `super` keyword to access a method of its superclass. So, in Child class, you may do `super.show();`.